# How to open QWebEngineView in a new window when a table cell is clicked?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qwebengineview

I am trying to open a Url in a QWebEngineView window when a QTableWidget cell is clicked.

The code for opening the QWebEngineView works from '**main**' but somehow it doesn't work when called from the subclass of QWidget. A window appears for a split second and then disappears. No error is shown on the console. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

```
class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Aplayers = [[14, 134, 13], [11, 144, 13]]
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(len(self.Aplayers), 3)
        self.setWindowTitle('Game Stats')
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 600, 400)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setData(self.Aplayers, self.tableWidget)
        self.tableWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.updateUiCellClick)
        self.show()


    def setData(self, players, tbl: QTableWidget):
        index = -1
        for row in players:
            index += 1
            tbl.setItem(index, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[1])))
            tbl.setItem(index, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[2])))
            tbl.setItem(index, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])))

    def updateUiCellClick(self, row):
        web = QWebEngineView()
        web.load(QUrl('https://www.google.com'))
        web.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = None
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWidget = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Create `self.webs = []` in the constructor and add `self.webs.append(web)` after `web.show()`

Answer (score 1):

The QWebEngineView is only available in the local scope of that function, so it disappears immediately after the function returns. If you call it `self.web` instead it will work, since the application will retain a pointer to the web engine view.

```
def updateUiCellClick(self, row):
    self.web = QWebEngineView()
    self.web.load(QUrl('https://www.google.com'))
    self.web.show()
```